# React router dom throws invalid hook call, cannot read properties of null, etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
import './interface/App.css';
import { Home } from './interface/home';
import { Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return ( 
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

this throws

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have no idea why, I was following some tutorials and failed. I have tried using `<Home/>` instead of Home, I updated all my packages including `react`, `react-dom`, `react-router-dom`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share a complete [mcve] that includes the imports? Can you also verify what version of `react-router` you are using? You can check the installed version by running `npm list react-router react-router-dom` in the terminal from the project's root directory.

Comment: react router dom and react router is both 6.3.0

Comment: I see, and the full & complete `App` code w/ imports?

Comment: Also, the <Router> is causing the problem. If I remove that, there are no errors.
@DrewReese

Comment: import './interface/App.css';
import { Home } from './interface/home';
import {Router, Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are using `react-router-dom@6` and using the low-level `Router` when you should import and use one of the high-level routers (*`BrowserRouter`, `MemoryRouter`, etc*) and you are using the RRDv5 `Route` component APIs. The `Router` component has a couple required props to make it work.

[Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/router)

> ```
> declare function Router(
>   props: RouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string;
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator;
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```

Missing from your code are the required `navigator` and `location` props which feed into an internal location context the low-level router holds.

## Solution

Import a high-level router, wrap the `Route` components in the `Routes` component, and render the routed content on the `element` prop as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. `component` (*and `render` and `children` function props`*) are v5 and don't exist in v6.

The high-level routers maintain their own history/location contexts internally.

Example:

```
import './interface/App.css';
import { Home } from './interface/home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return ( 
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's still the same. Errors!

Comment: @jkimishere Interesting. Think you could try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live? Feel free to fork this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-throws-invalid-hook-call-cannot-read-properties-of-null-etc-fhdlmz) I started.

Comment: Well, I made a codesandbox demo, but it works in codesandbox. Why? (exact same code)
@DrewReese

Comment: @jkimishere I suppose something is different for you locally. You said `react-router` ***and*** `react-router-dom` were both 6.3.0, you only need one of these added to you project. Are you sure of the *installed* version(s)? Can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
wait what? no react?

Comment: @jkimishere Yeah, you kind of need `react` installed for anything to work.  Run `npm i -S react@latest react-dom@latest` to install the current version of React and retest locally. If you still have issues after that can you share your package.json file?

Comment: I did install it now, still errors. :(

Comment: just added react and react dom.

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246475/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-jkimishere).